# Fortran SAVE attribute with implicit type

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I was trying to compile the following, and both gfortran and ifort reported a syntax error:

```
module test
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
allocatable, save :: A(:)
end module test
```

This is the `gfortran -c test.f90` output:

```
allocatable, save :: A(:)
            1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

and the `ifort -c test.f90` output:

```
test.f90(3): error #5277: Syntax error, found ',' following statement keyword
allocatable, save :: A(:)
------------^
test.f90(3): error #5082: Syntax error, found '::' when expecting one of: ( , <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; [
allocatable, save :: A(:)
------------------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

However, without the `save` attribute, or by adding an explicit type, it compiles fine:

```
module test
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
allocatable :: A(:)
end module test

module test
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
real*8, allocatable, save :: A(:)
end module test
```

Since both compilers report a syntax error, I wonder if this is a bug or not, or if someone knows what might have gone wrong?

Comment: IMO, implicit typing is obsolete.  Better to use `implicit none` and explicit typing.  As a bonus you would have used `allocatable` and `save` as attributes (as explained by IRO-bot) and they are allowed together.

Comment: I think it's debatable, but yes, usually I would go with `implicit none`. However, this is part of exercise to see if I can introduce allocatable arrays into an existing F77 code with lots of implicitly typed variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. From section 5.4.2 of the latest Fortran standard (or Metcalf, Reid and Cohen in more readable form), the `allocatable` statement may be used in the form:

```
allocatable [::] array-name [ (array-spec) ] [, array-name [ (array-spec) ]] ...
```

Thus, you have to use `allocatable` and `save` in separate statements. Both of the compilers that you used reported the error because they expected the array name after `allocatable`, but they encountered a comma.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the standards memorized? It seems you (and a few others) are able to pull out the exact chapter, section, paragraph, line, etc of the standard in a short few minutes of a question's asking.

Comment: Haha, no I just happen to have a pdf of the standard in the nearby directory and ctrl+f as a handy search utility.

Comment: but then, why does `real*8, allocatable, save :: A(:)` work fine? I found this page that lists compatible attributes for allocate: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf131.aix.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Falloabl.html

Comment: @steabert Because in that case, `allocatable` and `save` are not statements but attributes.

Comment: @IRO-bot: I see. My pdf copy is buried at least 3 directories deep, so I rarely go to it.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I edited the tag wiki (at least I suggested an edit) and added the links to the standards. Maybe it's faster to access them then ;-)